# The dismiss listener of a pop up window is invoked when return button is clicked but not invoked when the screen rotates

Tags: android, popup

In an Android application,

On a pop up window, when the screen rotates, the pop up window disappears

I've put a dismiss listener there and when the return button is clicked, the listener is invoked
It is working fine

```
   popupWindow.setOnDismissListener(new PopupWindow.OnDismissListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDismiss() {

                // it is working fine when the pop up is dismissed by the return click

            }
        });
```

The point is when the screen rotates, this listener is not invoked even though the pop up window is disappeared, Why?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved:

```
        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();

            if (popupWindow != null)
            {
                if ( popupWindow.isShowing() == true) {
                    popupWindow.dismiss();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

on screen rotation onSaveInstanceState() get called, and after it when you wants to restore the activity state then you have to call onRestoreInstanceState() and then call your respective functions from it.

```
@Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        // call your here event listeners from here again
        initComponants();
        initComponantsListener();
        bindData();  

    }
```

Good practice is puting all inititialtion of componants in initComponants(), all 
   listner events in initComponantsListener() and binding data in bindData()...